# The default change to DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

i'm using in library  dataTables  In the folder **jquery.dataTables.min**
And there is the option to display 10 rows or 25 or 50 or 100
10 rows are the default
How do I change the default to 50 rows?
Below is just the code that shows the options:

```
    aLengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    iDisplayLength: 10,
```

Comment: Firstly, you can do this using [`pagelength`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength). Secondly, from the property names it looks like you're using a **very old** version of Datatables, which you should update ASAP

Comment: Also, remove the very odd usage of `!0` and `!1`. Just use `true` and `false` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change its iDisplayLength to 50

Comment: The array remains the same?

Comment: Yes you just need to set iDisplayLength to 50 and array will be the value you want in drop-down.
If you want the page size must be 25,50,100,500, or some thing like this then change the array.